# Query MySQL date with DAYOFWEEK

Tags: mysql, date

My MySQL table (bars with different open days):

```
id  name    days_open
----------------------------------------
1   diner   mo tu we th fr
2   joes    fr sa su
3   jimmy   sa su
4   tree    su mo
```

My problem: I look for the bars open for the next 7,14 or 30 days. First date is now: 2018-01-10 (we)

This should be the result of the query:

```
date        name
----------------------------------------
2018-01-10  diner       (we)

2018-01-11  diner       (th)

2018-01-12  diner       (fr)
2018-01-12  joes        (fr)

2018-01-13  joes        (sa)
2018-01-13  jimmy       (sa)

2018-01-14  joes        (su)
2018-01-14  jimmy       (su)
2018-01-14  tree        (su)

...
```

next  days (7, 14 or 30)

I have already tried several requests with DAYOFWEEK (CURDATE ()), but did not get a correct result.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? The days_open column doesn't seem to be the best way to store that information and might make the query quite complex. Is it possible for you to change it?

Comment: I tried several UNION ans SELECT queries. I can still change the table with open_days.

Comment: Here is a suggestion about the table: make days_open a separate table with Id and Day. So it will have `1 Mo`, `1 Tu`, .... `1 Fr`, `2 Fr`...and so on. Then you can have a temp table with the dates you need to select the open restaurants for...So it would be `1/10 We`, `1/11 Th`... And then join all three tables. That should get you exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately it exceeds my current knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Change your table design like below and use any server side language looping for next 15 or 30 days. Or write procedure to get next 30 days list.

```
users
-----

id  name   
-----------
1   diner  
2   joes   
3   jimmy  
4   tree   

day_opens
---------

id  day user_id
-------------------------
1   2   1
2   3   1
3   4   1
4   6   2
5   7   2


SELECT CURDATE(), u.name, DAYNAME(CURDATE()) FROM day_opens o, users u WHERE o.user_id = u.id AND o.day = DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE());
```

if you using server side language change your query like below and dynamically change the interval day.

```
SELECT ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), u.name, DAYNAME(ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) FROM day_opens o, users u WHERE o.user_id = u.id AND o.day = DAYOFWEEK(ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

Comment: Thank you I test it in the next few days.